# What is the purpose of all these headers when the PHP readfile function is used to download a file?

Tags: php, file-io, http-headers, download, cache-control

In the past, I have used the PHP `readfile` function in combination with some header declarations to automatically download files. Usually, my script looks something like the following:

```
<?php

  $url = 'url-to-some-resource';

  header('Content-Disposition: application; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

  readfile($url);
```

However, looking at the [`readfile` page on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/readfile), I noticed that they recommend using a lot more headers to achieve exactly the same thing. Specifically, they example they provide on the page looks like the following:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

What is the purpose of all those headers? I get the Content-Length header, but beyond that, why set the Content-Description, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Expires, Cache-Control and Pragma headers?

I ask because my basic script with only two headers always seems to work for me, and I've never encountered a situation in which the script didn't work.

As a side question, why does the PHP.net example execute the `ob_clean` and `flush` functions right before the `readfile` function?

Comment: They're telling the other side of the connection, e.g. your users' browsers, what to do with the file. "This is a text/plain file, it's X bytes long, and you should treat it as a download, not something to display in the browser", blah blah blah. All of those headers are defined in the HTTP/1.0 and /1.1 specs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Marc B. I kind of already knew that much though. I was kind of hoping for a more detailed response regarding the headers that I'm not familiar with. I have looked at the HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 specs, but to be honest, they're somewhat hard to understand, so I was hoping for a slightly more layman's explanation. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: in this explicity case, the cache headers are telling the browser to NOT cache the file. content-description would could used to display to the user what they're actually receiving. "This is the file you're about to download". as for the encoding, it could be base64, 7bit, 8bit, etc... binary is easiest because you're just duping out literal bytes with no translation.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Thank you very much.